# Process a single connection with multiple threads

Tags: netty

I have 3 async servers and clients connected each other, like a chain.

A request goes through the 3 system like

`=> System 1 => System 2 => System 3 =>`

And the response

`=> System 3 => System 2 => System 1 =>`

I have a logic in each of this systems in order to join the response with the correct request. With that logic I manage to process responses and requests in different order.

Today I have only a single connection between the systems. And I notice that only one thread is used, and the performance is not good... :(

Are there any configuration to force use more than one thread per connection?
Is this the correct way of solve this problems? Or I have to have a pool of connection between each systems?, Has netty some kind of this pool or I have to implement it by my own?

I'm using netty 5.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Netty wikis](http://netty.io/wiki/new-and-noteworthy-in-4.0.html#wiki-h2-34) for a good general description of the threading model.  In summary Netty 4.0+ will not introduce concurrency into the channel handling operations.  Check out the majority of the [netty examples](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example) and you will notice the lack of synchronization because of this. Operating on channels concurrently would introduce more complexity to the framework and interface to interact with the framework.

I think the question is does your use case support being split amongst multiple channels? It depends upon a lot of factors but if you algorithms and data support parallelization then you may see improvements in overall throughput.

Netty does provide a [ChannelGroup](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/transport/src/main/java/io/netty/channel/group/ChannelGroup.java) but I'm not sure if this fits in with your usecase.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
The question one is:
If netty supposes to work in this way. After reading the documentation with more care and your comment, I think the response is yes.

The second question is:
If we suppose that my data and use case allow to make multiple connections, I should create multiple connections ( all asynchronous ) or make only one?

I resume, netty makes a good use of CPU and their cores with multiple connections and not too much with only one?

Comment: You are interpreting this answer correctly. 1) No concurrency for a single channel by Netty. 2) Netty is designed to handle many channels.  Your application must provide the design and implementation for how to use these all these channels.  Pooling is 1 alternative.  [Object pooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) and [connection pooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool) are a patterns in their own rights and you can read up on when/why they are beneficial (or ask another question :) ).

Comment: Although it quite some time, I found this question quite pertaining to a requirement I have where there is one or few clients for a server, but these clients generate large amount of traffic. Is it possible to use multithreaded `EventExecutor` to the channel handlers in the pipeline so that instead of channel `EventLoop`, the concurrency is achieved by the `EventExecutor` thread pool? Will it ensure that one message from the client will be handled by one thread through all handlers, while the next message by another thread? Is there any sample source available?