# Using Netty to build a server with only few clients

Tags: java, multithreading, netty

I am familiar with `Netty` basics and have used it to build a typical application server running on TCP designed to serve many clients/connections. However, I recently have a requirement to build a server which is designed to handle handful of clients or only one client most of the times. But the client is the gateway to many devices and therefore generate substantial traffic to the server I am trying to design.

My questions are:

- Is it possible / recommended at all to use `Netty` for this use case? I have seen the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26824517/process-a-single-connection-with-multiple-threads).
- Is it possible to use multithreaded EventExecutor to the channel handlers in the pipeline so that instead of channel EventLoop, the concurrency is achieved by the EventExecutor thread pool? Will it ensure that one message from the client will be handled by one thread through all handlers, while the next message by another thread?
- Is there any example implementation available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://netty.io/4.1/api/index.html) of `io.netty.channel.oio` you can use it if you don't have lot's of client. In this case, every connection will be handled in a separate thread and use Java old blocking IO under the hood. Take a look at `OioByteStreamChannel::activate`:

```
/**
 * Activate this instance. After this call {@link #isActive()} will return {@code true}.
 */
protected final void activate(InputStream is, OutputStream os) {
    if (this.is != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("input was set already");
    }
    if (this.os != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("output was set already");
    }
    if (is == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("is");
    }
    if (os == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("os");
    }
    this.is = is;
    this.os = os;
}
```

As you can see, the oio `Stream`s will be used there.

According to your comment. You can Specify `EventExecutorGroup` while adding handler to a pipeline as this:

```
new ChannelInitializer<Channel> {
      public void initChannel(Channel ch) {
          ch.pipeline().addLast(new YourHandler());
      }
}
```

Let's take a look at the `AbstractChannelHandlerContext`:

```
@Override
public EventExecutor executor() {
    if (executor == null) {
        return channel().eventLoop();
    } else {
        return executor;
    }
}
```

Here we see that if you don't register your `EventExecutor` it will use the child event group you specified while creating the `ServerBootstrap`.

```
new ServerBootstrap()
      .group(new OioEventLoopGroup(), new OioEventLoopGroup())
               //acceptor group          //child group
```

Here is how reading from channel is invoked `AbstractChannelHandlerContext::invokeChannelRead`:

```
static void invokeChannelRead(final AbstractChannelHandlerContext next, Object msg) {
    final Object m = next.pipeline.touch(ObjectUtil.checkNotNull(msg, "msg"), next);
    EventExecutor executor = next.executor();
    if (executor.inEventLoop()) {
        next.invokeChannelRead(m);
    } else {
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {   //Invoked by the EventExecutor you specified
            @Override
            public void run() {
                next.invokeChannelRead(m);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible for me to use `EventExecutor` for the handlers in the pipeline while using OIO?

Comment: @SoumyaKanti Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, really helpful for me.

Comment: @SoumyaKanti You are welcome. To understand, how the `EventGroup` is registered for a child `Channel` you can take a look at `private static class ServerBootstrapAcceptor`

Comment: Sure, will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Even for a few connections I would go with `NioEventLoopGroup`.

Regarding your question:

> Is it possible to use multithreaded EventExecutor to the channel
>   handlers in the pipeline so that instead of channel EventLoop, the
>   concurrency is achieved by the EventExecutor thread pool? Will it
>   ensure that one message from the client will be handled by one thread
>   through all handlers, while the next message by another thread?

Netty's `Channel` guarantees that every processing for an inbound or an outbound message will occur in the same thread. You don't have to hack an `EventExecutor` of your own to handle this. If serving inbound messages doesn't require long-lasting processings your code will look like basic usage of `ServerBootstrap`. You might find useful to tune the number of threads in the pool.